# Need help formally translating sentence into modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic, translation

Can someone please help me formally translate the sentence "it is impossible for x to exist without y existing as well" into modal logic using ~◇? Or, similarly, the sentence "it is impossible for both x to be the case and not y to be the case." Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a predicate ‘**E**’ expressing ‘actually exists’ ?

Comment: No but what would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that we can treat **x** and **y** as *constants* (i.e. "names") :

> **~◊ (∃z(z=x) & ~∃w(w=y))**.